# check if variable is either string/int/float?

Tags: go

Got this type `map[string]interface{}` because I want to allow a map with both `strings` and `integers`

But how can the map be converted into `map[string]string` and return errors if any values are "unsupported"?

```
value, ok := v.(string)
```

This will throw an error if the value is an integer

Comment: The type assertion in the question does not “throw an error” when the value is a number.  Use the type assertion on each value and return an error when ok is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go supports [type switches](https://go.dev/tour/methods/16):

For your use case it would look something like:

```
m := map[string]string{}
for k,v := range values {
    switch value := v.(type) {
        switch value := v.(type) {
        case int:
            m[k] = fmt.Sprintf("%v", value)

        case float64:
            m[k] = fmt.Sprintf("%v", value)

        case string:
            m[k] = fmt.Sprintf("%v", value)

       default:
            return nil,fmt.Errorf("unknown type %T", v)
    }
}

return m,nil
```

You can combine the cases into a single case if you prefer, e.g.              https://play.golang.com/p/XrM7ABJ8Gok